# Rails 3 can't get beginning_of_week

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Have a publish_on datetime field.

Just trying to get to the begining_of_week from the publish_on.

Tried a helper

```
def start_week(publish_on)
  DateTime.parse(publish_on).beginning_of_week
end
```

and in view `<%= start_week(@survey.publish_on) %>`

Tried in my model

```
def set_start_week
  publish_on.beginning_of_week
end
```

Hell, even tried this helper

```
def this_should_work
  DateTime.now.beginning_of_week
end
```

But everything returns a invalid date to my view.  It works in irb, why not in my view?

### EDIT

```
module SurveysHelper
  require 'date'
  require 'time'

  def this_should_work
    DateTime.now.beginning_of_week
  end
end
```

take_survey.html.erb

```
<%= this_should_work %>
```

Error
`invalid date`

Comment: Can you post the error? DateTime.now.beginning_of_week works in a view for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails 3.0.9 I got

```
undefined method `at_beginning_of_week'
```

wherever I put it, my alternative solution is:

```
def SomeMethodPutAnywhere
...
@datey = Date.today
@monday = @datey - @datey.wday + 1

#@monday is now the monday of the current week.
#Remove the constant '+1' if your week begins sunday...
...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem when trying to use ActiveSupport outside of Rails. I found the answer here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html

Here is the key bit:

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

Have you customized your rails stack to no longer include ActiveSupport?